# How to run scheduled serverless lifecycle script on objects in Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, backup, azure-blob-storage, serverless

I have a script copying a daily backup file to Blob storage using azcopy. On the Blob objects I want to create a lifecycle policy, like GFS, for the backups. Then I want to move older data (perhaps the yearly backup files) to colder storage automatically. Then I need to charge my client per GB storage and need a monthly report, maybe an e-mail, to our finance department with the month's maximum storage GB value. I will develop this and need guidance on where to start. Please point me in the right direction. As cheap and serverless as possible. I will answer my own question with the scripts etc to share the knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's recommended approach for such scheduled jobs/workflows is [Azure Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/logic-apps/)

Microsoft have developed an extensive 'drag and drop' web UI to allow you to easily define actions such as moving data amongst storage containers, sending e-mails, etc. and then link these actions into workflows.

Here's a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow) to a useful quickstart guide.